# Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server"

Tags: filezilla

I am trying to connect to a networked machine's FileZilla server but my FileZilla Client is giving the following error while connecting. The error is:

> "Connection attempt failed with ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server"

Windows Firewall is turned off on that machine and i had provided the valid credentials in my FTP Client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Server Fault has a canonical question about [Connection Refused](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message).

Comment: FTP server misconfiguration.

Comment: check the link  [filezilla-help](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) and this [image-link](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/wiki/images/d/d9/Settings_activemode.png)

Comment: instead of site name in domain give FTP hostname from your control panel and it will work with 21 port for ftp...

Comment: Just make  http://localhost:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000. It works

Answer (score 97):

FTP protocol may be blocked by your ISP firewall, try connecting via SFTP (i.e. use 22 for port num instead of 21 which is simply FTP).

For more information try [this link](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration).

Comment: select SFTP and account type should be - normal  and port -22 ..cheers!!!

Comment: Great tip on difference between port numbers 22 and 21

Comment: its work.... :)

Comment: Totally works !

Answer (score 39):

Use port number 22 (for sftp) instead of 21 (normal ftp). Solved this problem for me.

Comment: You need a SFTP-Server to use the port number 22. It does not work for a normal web server with FTP connection!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this error

```
A connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server"
```

by changing my port to 22 that was successful

Comment: Any chance on more details that might help others? Which port, where to change that.

Comment: You change the port when you save the server or, when using quick connect, the Port: text box immediately left of the Quickconnect button.  Note: Quickconnect uses port 21 (SFTP/SSH) by default.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was receiving this error when connecting to the new IP Address I had configured FileZilla to bind to and saved the configuration. After trying all of the other answers unsuccessfully, I decided to connect to the old IP Address to see what came up; lo and behold it responded.

I restarted the FileZilla Windows Service and it immediately came back listening on the correct IP. Pretty elementary, but it cost me some time today as a noob to FZ.

Hopefully this helps someone out in the same predicament.